# IList<T>.FindIndex(Int32, Predicate <T>)

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

There is a `List<T>.FindIndex(Int32, Predicate <T>)`. That method is exactly what I want to for a `IList<T>` object.
I know `IList` has a method `IndexOf(T)` but I need the predicate to define the comparing algorithm.

Is there a method, extension method, LINQ or some code to find the index of an item in a `IList<T>`?

Comment: I thought there are some LINQ calls to do that. But if I combine e.g. `Where(...)` with something else the index is lost.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Well you can *really* easily write your own extension method:

```
public static int FindIndex<T>(this IList<T> source, int startIndex,
                               Predicate<T> match)
{
    // TODO: Validation
    for (int i = startIndex; i < source.Count; i++)
    {
        if (match(source[i]))
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```